# Почему при работе с react-popout вылетает ошибка?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Использую [данный плагин](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-popout). Есть страница, на которой после клику по кнопке будет всплывать попаут. Прикрутить я его прикрутил и худо бедно открыть можно но есть проблема. Вот как я его использовал.Создал компонент:

```
var PopoutWindow = React.createClass({


    render: function () {
        var url = (this.props.url != null) ? this.props.url : "";
        var title = (this.props.title != null) ? this.props.title : "";


        if (this.props.isPoppedOut){
              return (
                <Popout url={url}
                        title={title}
                >
                </Popout>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                null
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Вот как записал его в рендере родительского компонента :

```
<PopoutWindow   url=''
                title='POPUP'
                isPoppedOut={this.state.isPoppedOut}
/>
```

Тут же ниже кнопка:

```
<button type="submit" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.popupOpen} className="btn">
 Install
</button>
```

Метод `popupOpen`, который также обозначен в родителе:

```
popupOpen: function () {
        if(this.state.isPoppedOut) {
            this.setState({isPoppedOut: false});
        } else {
            this.setState({isPoppedOut: true});
        }
    },
```

По клику на кнопку хендлер срабатывает и появляется новое окно в браузере, однако в консоли он пишет ошибку:

```
Uncaught Error: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element.
```

Погуглил и увиделп охожие ошибки у людей в сети.Они связаны с неправильным пробросом в `ReactDOM.render()`, не совсем понял это. у меня рендерится в определенном контейнере все приложение сов сем своими компонентами. Этой штуке нужен отдельный контейнер для рендера?
И еще небольшой вопрос касаемо закрытия. Подозреваю,что оно как-то реализовано иначе, чем у меня. Если кнопкой открыть окно, но закрыть его нажав мышкой  по кнопке х на панели, то isPopedOut не перейдет в false и в дальнейшем,чтобы его открыть надо дважды кликнуть по моей кнопке.не совсем понял, как это реализовать нормально

Comment: PopoutWindow добавьте onClosing={this.popupOpen} и решиться вопрос с закрытием. Как я понимаю ошибка рендера из-за того что ничего нет ничего в PopoutWindow. Может попробывать туда воткнуть пустой <div></div>?

Comment: да,вы правы.добавил пустой див в компонент и ошибка пропала.спасибо. если вас не затруднит,продублируйте в ответ. я выберу его и закрою вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<PopoutWindow   url=''
                title='POPUP'
                isPoppedOut={this.state.isPoppedOut}
/>
```

Здесь добавьте `onClosing={this.popupOpen}`(обработчик события закрытия окна) и добавить пустой `<div>` внутрь этого компонента.